# How can I put valid YANG instance data in a well-formed XML document when there are leafref nodes in it?

Tags: xml, yang

I'm having trouble combining two things: YANG data modeling, and off-the-shelf XML tools. Specifically, when the YANG module has leafref's to another module, I can't see how to avoid having two top-level tags.

As a stripped down example, consider these two yang models and some valid instance data:

a.yang:

```
module a {
  namespace "aspace";
  prefix a;

  typedef baz-ref {
    type leafref {
      path "/a:foo/a:bar/a:baz";
    }
  }

  container foo {
    container bar {
      leaf baz {
        type string;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

b.yang:

```
module b {
  namespace "bspace";
  prefix b;
  import a {
    prefix a;
  }

  container qux {
    container quux {
      leaf baz {
        type a:baz-ref;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

valid.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo xmlns="aspace"><bar><baz>valid</baz></bar></foo>
<qux xmlns="bspace"><quux><baz>valid</baz></quux></qux>
```

I can use yanglint just fine on that "xml" file:

```
$ yanglint -s b.yang -t config valid.xml
```

But I can't use, eg, Python's xml module, to parse it, because it has two top-level tags:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.ElementTree(file='valid.xml')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 557, in __init__
    self.parse(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 597, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: junk after document element: line 3, column 0
>>>
```

Alternatively, if I use this XML, invalid.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data xmlns="whatever">
<foo xmlns="aspace"><bar><baz>invalid</baz></bar></foo>
<qux xmlns="bspace"><quux><baz>invalid</baz></quux></qux>
</data>
```

I can parse/create it fine in Python (or other XML tools):

```
>>> tree = ET.ElementTree(file='invalid1.xml')
>>> tree
<xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree object at 0x7ff4f629ef60>
>>>
```

But yanglint doesn't like it:

```
$ yanglint -s b.yang -t config invalid1.xml 
err : Unknown element "data". (/)
$
```

In the actual project I'm working on a.yang and b.yang are IEEE standards (from [802.1CBcv](https://github.com/YangModels/yang/tree/master/standard/ieee/draft/802.1/CBcv), in case the details matter), meaning I can't touch them. But I'm hoping there's a way to write a new yang module that lets me put <foo> and <qux> underneath the same top-level tag in the XML file, and still have yanglint validate the instance data against the standard. Since the yang modules I have use containers instead of groupings, I can't figure out how to import their data definitions as children of some higher-level container in a new yang module.

The only thing I *can* get working is to write multiple .xml files, and have yanglint merge them and validate the whole data tree, with something like:

foo.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo xmlns="aspace"><bar><baz>valid</baz></bar></foo>
```

qux.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<qux xmlns="bspace"><quux><baz>valid</baz></quux></qux>
```

yanglint command:

```
$ yanglint -m -s b.yang -t config foo.xml qux.xml
```

However, with these particular yang models that would require hundreds of separate .xml files because the data definition in ieee802-dot1cb-stream-identification.yang is a list, and we expect there to be very many elements in that list.

Is there a best practice for this sort of situation?

Comment: PS, The instance data in [this yanglint example](https://plajjan.github.io/2019-02-23-simple-data-validation-with-YANG-using-yanglint.html) I found online has a top-level tag that is generic, and different from what's in the yang module, but when I run it I get an error from yanglint, unlike the results from that blog. So maybe something is off about my libyang install or something.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to parse such xml files? Try the following method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo xmlns="aspace"><bar><baz>valid</baz></bar></foo>
<qux xmlns="bspace"><quux><baz>valid</baz></quux></qux>
'''

doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
print (doc.foo.baz.text)
print (doc.qux.text)
```

Result:

```
valid
valid
```

Comment: I need to generate those files, but I will look at that module. I've been using lxml for almost everything, but at this point I'm open to trying something different if it will get the job done.